# Find Range Name Using Active Cell

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming in VBA.

I have one cell that is part of a named range.  Using that active cell, I want to be able to find what range that cell is a part of and pass it into a VBA function or subroutine as a Range object.

Can anyone provide me with guidance as to how to proceed, or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A single cell can be part of several ranges, do you want to list all of them ??

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example.

The code checks if the selected cell is part of a named range. If so, the named range is passed to a function:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim nm As Integer

    For nm = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
       If Not Intersect(Selection, Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm).Name)) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print MyFunc(Range(ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm).Name)) // Prints TRUE or FALSE
       End If
    Next nm
End Sub

Function MyFunc(Named_Range As Range) As Boolean
    MyFunc = Named_Range.Cells.Count > 2  ~~>Courtesy of `Thomas Inzina`
End Function
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just use: MyFunc = Named_Range.Cells.Count > 2

Comment: Shouldn't you check single cell named ranges as well? And ignore `Print_Area` and `_FilterDatabase` ranges?  I'll just shut up - you did say _simple example_, so shows the process needed. :)